# Rationale behind postgresql age(timestamp) function semantics

Tags: postgresql

This just came up at work and I was wondering what the rationale behind this function is

```
function        Description
age(timestamp)  Subtract from current_date (at midnight)
```

It was asked why does this subtract the given date from midnight? Instead of subtracting it from now()? Is there a reason? Or is it just because?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both forms of `age()` take [`timestamp`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-datetime.html) as parameter(s), not `date`. If you supply a `date`, it's converted to the according `timestamp` at midnight.

The one-parameter form calculates age against today, midnight, which is obviously the most useful default:

- If you supply a `timestamp`, you get an interval of days, plus the time difference to midnight.
- If you supply a `date`, you get an interval of days.

These are stable, readily useful, easily comprehensible results.
If age would be calculated against `now()`, it would be none of these. You can always do that explicitly by using the two-parameter form.

So these expressions yield the same result:

```
SELECT age(now())
     , age(now()::date, now())
     , age(date_trunc('day', now()), now());
```